# How to work out consumption of a battery after powering an electric motor?

Tags: voltage, batteries, motor, power-consumption

Hi friends I'm trying to work out how many kWh of energy capacity are drained from a high voltage battery after powering an electric motor for a period of time in a little study on an electric vehicle.

I've measured that during a test drive the electric motor was powered using 282kW of power for a period of 843 seconds (or 0.23 of an hour).

This would equate to the electric motor using about 66kWh energy during the test drive.

But how can I then work out how much kWh has been drained from the battery if the battery is rated at 40.4 kWh?

Thanks

Comment: It seems unlikely that the motor was consuming 282 kW (375 hp!) continuously for the entire drive. You need to measure the actual instantaneous power going to the motor and integrate it over time to find the energy consumed.

Comment: Ah I see thanks for the advice

Comment: How did you determine that the motor used 282kW for 843 seconds?